# Creating field with multiple properties

Tags: 8, entities, plugins

I am creating a Field plugin, where I have requirement as below

**Field name :** Question

**Properties:**

Question Text : String

Question Type : integer (0,1,2)

Question Options : Array of Strings

I defined schema like this. I am not sure if I am doing it right for Question Option

```
public static function schema(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition) {
    $schema = [
        'columns' => [
            'question_text' => [
                'type' => 'varchar',
            ],
            'option_type' => [
                'description' => 'Option Type: 0 = radio, 1 = checkbox',
                'type' => 'int',
                'default' => 0,
            ],
            'question_option' => [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'serialize' => TRUE,
            ],
        ],
    ];

    return $schema;
}
```

And for property definition I have following

```
public static function propertyDefinitions(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition) {

    $properties['question_text'] = DataDefinition::create('string');
    $properties['option_type'] = DataDefinition::create('integer');

    $properties['question_option'] = DataDefinition::create('string');

    return $properties;
}
```

Please let me know how can I do it for the question_option.

--

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an array of strings maybe your should use a blob in you schema:

```
 'question_option' => [
          'type' => 'blob',
          'size' => 'big',
          'not null' => TRUE,
          'serialize' => TRUE
        ],
```

Note that by default 'size' = 'normal' which max storage value is 16KB so if it is enough for you use 'big'; 'big' can handle up to 4GB.
And for properties as follow:

```
$properties['question_options'] = MapDataDefinition::create()->setLabel(t('Options'))
```

Comment: Yes I used the same. Only one difference. Instead of DataDefinition I used MapDataDefinition. $properties['options'] = MapDataDefinition::create()->setLabel(t('Options'));

Comment: Nice, so i'll correct my post with your feedback!